# Oracle select to get summary

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, summary

Say I have two database tables `T1` and `T2`. `T1` has some column `C1` (among others) with values, say 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, null, null. `T2` has column `C2` (among others) with values, say 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, null. I wish to get a summary of these two columns, i.e. in one query, if possible, get to know how many times each value (null included) occurred in both columns combined. In this case, 1 occurred 4 times, 2 occurred 4 times, 3 and 4 occurred once, 5 occurred twice and null occurred 3 times.
I do not know in advance all the possible values in the columns.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `group by` on top of a `union all` query:

```
SELECT   value, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT c1 AS value
          FROM   t1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT c2 AS value
          FROM   t2)
GROUP BY value
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending your table size, your data distribution and maybe the index eventually available on `C1` and `C2`, you might expect better performances by using a query like the following, as Oracle don't have to build the full union of both table.

```
SELECT C, SUM(N) FROM
(
    SELECT C1 AS C, COUNT(*) AS N FROM T1 GROUP BY C1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C2, COUNT(*) FROM T2 GROUP BY C2
)
GROUP BY C;
```

That being said, YMMV. So if this is critical, I would suggest you to carefully examine the query execution plan in order to choose the "right" solution for your particular case.